# Link error on Mac OSX 10.6.7

Tags: macos, linker, linker-errors

I'm seeing:

```
ld: in objs/AttributeValueTest.o, can't link with a main executable for architecture x86_64
```

When building a very simple program which has only 1 .h and 1 .cpp file.

The compile lines are:

```
g++ -g -I./ -I/usr/local/include -o objs/AttributeValueTest.o tp_datastruct/tests/AttributeValueTest.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lavrocpp -lcppunit -lm 
g++ -g -I./ -I/usr/local/include -o AttributeValueTest objs/AttributeValueTest.o -L/usr/local/lib -lavrocpp -lcppunit -lm
```

I tried to specify -arch x86_64, -arch i386 and -m32, but nothing worked (I got other errors, it was complaining that libcppunit was not in the right format).

Any idea/pointer/suggestion?

Thanks!

---

Very strange. I did some digging around, and saw somewhere that AttributeValueTest.o might be an executable already. I did a "file" on that AttributeValueTest.o, and sure enough, it is a ready-to-go executable. I modified my makefile to rename that .o into AttributeValueTest, and I can happily run it. Also, the executable comes with a ".dSYM" directory, which I can remove without any problem... I don't understand what is going on, but I can run my executable now...

Comment: Very strange. I did some digging around, and saw somewhere that AttributeValueTest.o might be an executable already. I did a "file" on that AttributeValueTest.o, and sure enough, it is a ready-to-go executable. I modified my makefile to rename that .o into AttributeValueTest, and I can happily run it. Also, the executable comes with a ".dSYM" directory, which I can remove without any problem... I don't understand what is going on, but I can run my executable now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to specify `-c` option to the `g++` to compile a source code into object file. So it is getting compiled and linked into executable file. Then you are trying to link executable into executable, which fails. From the `gcc`'s manual page:

> -c  Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The
>   linking stage simply is not done.  The
>   ultimate output is in the form of an
>   object file for each source file.
>
> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by
>   r> eplacing the suffix .c, .i, .s, etc.,
>   with .o. Unrecognized input files, not
>   requiring compilation or assembly, are
>   ignored.